# how to store from database into following java object

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to store data in the following format ?

```
var markers = {
    type: "FeatureCollection",
    features: $.map([
        {
            coordinates: [-74, 40.7],
            text: "New York City",
            value: 8406
        },
        {
            coordinates: [100.47, 13.75],
            text: "Bangkok",
            value: 8281
        },
        {
            coordinates: [44.43, 33.33],
            text: "Baghdad",
            value: 7181
        },
        {
            coordinates: [37.62, 55.75],
            text: "Moscow",
            value: 12111
        },
        {
            coordinates: [121.5, 31.2],
            text: "Shanghai",
            value: 24150
        },
        {
            coordinates: [-43.18, -22.9],
            text: "Rio de Janeiro",
            value: 6429
        },
        {
            coordinates: [31.23, 30.05],
            text: "Cairo",
            value: 8922
        },
        {
            coordinates: [28.95, 41],
            text: "Istanbul",
            value: 14160
        },
        {
            coordinates: [127, 37.55],
            text: "Seoul",
            value: 10388
        },
        {
            coordinates: [139.68, 35.68],
            text: "Tokyo",
            value: 9071
        },
        {
            coordinates: [103.83, 1.28],
            text: "Singapore",
            value: 5399
        },
        {
            coordinates: [30.3, 59.95],
            text: "Saint Petersburg",
            value: 5131
        },
        {
            coordinates: [28.03, -26.2],
            text: "Johannesburg",
            value: 4434
        },
        {
            coordinates: [144.95, -37.8],
            text: "Melbourne",
            value: 4252
        }
    ], function (data) {
        return {
            type: "Feature",
            geometry: {
                type: "Point",
                markers: data.coordinates
            },
            properties: {
                text: data.text,
                value: data.value,
                tooltip: "<b>" + data.text + "</b>\n" + data.value + "K"
            }
        };
    })
};
```

If my database contains value of latitude , longitude , count as value, postalcode as Text

```
CT  postcode    latitude    longitude
1   EC1WER      51.52514    -0.111183
3   E1 WQP      51.5125     -0.052098
3   EC1WER      51.52514    -0.111183
```

Answer (score 0):

it is clear that you want to store 2d object into the Db.
mongoDb is good for un-structured data storage. you can take that benefit by using Geo-Json.
Here is the link
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/

You can have many functionality like co-ordinate intersect, geoWithin, geoNear... etc.